# Populate an input with a specific option using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down that contains 2 options. For this instance I need to pre-populate a specific value from this list. Is there a way to make this happen using this form of a drop-down? Below is what I have tried, but doesn't seem to work.

```
vm.recycle = [];
        angular.forEach(vm.allLists.recycle, function(val, idx) {
            vm.recycle.push({
                value: val.id,
                name: val.recycle,
                //vm.recycleDefault: {id: 'Y', name: 'Option 1'}
            });

        });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/OD665pG5bXdDC1nuLMxN?p=preview

Is there a simple way to tell it I want option 1 or option 2? Sorry for not including everything, but the controller is large.

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular wrong.

Define model

```
vm.myval = null
vm.allLists.recycle  = [...]

vm.chooseOption = function() {
   if (allisgood) vm.myval = 'X' else vm.myval = 'Y'      
}
```

And bind it:

```
<select ng-model='vm.myval' ng-options='vm.allLists.recycle' />

<button ng-click='vm.chooseOption()' >select</button>
```